# Creating a custom rewrite for a single page

Tags: url-rewriting

I am quite new to working within wordpress but am getting along quite smoothly.

I have setup a website where its downloading external JSON data from rapid-api and then displaying them in my design. The data is about Football/Soccer teams.

I have setup a page that is `url/team-info/?id=123`

In here its fetching the id from the url and downloading that specific teams information from the json.

That all works perfectly, but I am having to use a PHP snippet plugin in order for it to work.

I then wanted to create a rewrite rule to change it from `url/team-info/?id=123` to `url/team-info/123`

I originally tried editing the htaccess file directly but that threw up all sorts of 500 errors, so I put the original back and left it as it was.

I then have seen lots of posts about adding in code like so into the 'init hook', something I am not familiar with in wordpress, back to 2013 and 2014, I am sure these will be out dated so am looking for guidance.

So far I have learned the page in question is `/?page_id=735` which then `?page_id=735&id=123` also works.

I look forward to your guidance on this matter and if you have any furtur questions please let me know.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to achieve something beyond simple theme changes, so it would benefit you to read more of the WP documentation - to learn about hooks like "init" and to understand how WP create rewrite rules - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/

Comment: @QStudio Thanks for the comment, I will read upon that, try out what I learn and then come back here with any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of the link provided by @q-studio I was able to determine the correct course of action.

Firstly I setup an action to load the code in the `init` using the 'init' tags in an `add_action();` within my functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpteaminfo_init' );
```

Then i created the function to setup my id variable with `add_rewrite_tag();` then I added a rewrite rule with `add_rewrite_rule();`

```
function wpteaminfo_init()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%id%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^team-info/([0-9]{1,})/?','index.php?page_id=735&id=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Finally on my page due to using a php snippet to get and style the json data I had to create a variable from the final part of the url.

this was accomplished by using `get_query_var();` and putting the variable name within the brackets.

In my case i set the code up using this

```
$requestid = get_query_var( 'id' );
```

then the result was by having the url as so `url/team-info/123/` it was returning the id which in this case is 123, sending it to the webpage in a usable variable `$requestid`.

I hope this helps anyone who finds it.

-Adam